# While using flush() method : "Automatic conversion to JSON is not supported for response type."

Tags: angular, unit-testing

While I'm using the `flush()` method for testing HTTP requests I have this error:

> Automatic conversion to JSON is not supported for response type.

Can you also explain me the goal of the flush() method. I don't really understand it.

**The problem was not really solved. We have  to add async() method to the "it " function like that :  "it('should get the post', async(() => {**

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController} from "@angular/common/http/testing"
import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Post } from './post.model';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

describe('DataService', () => {

  let service: DataService
  let  httpTestingController: HttpTestingController
  let attemptedPost : Post;
  const post = {
    userId: 1,
    id: 1,
    title: "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    body: "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  };


  beforeEach(() => { TestBed.configureTestingModule({

    imports : [HttpClientTestingModule,HttpClientModule],
    providers : [DataService]
  });

    service = TestBed.get(DataService);
    httpTestingController = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController)
});

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should get the post', () => {


    service.getPosts().subscribe( (postRetrieved) => {

      attemptedPost=postRetrieved;
    }); 

   const req =  httpTestingController.expectOne('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');
   req.flush(attemptedPost);
   // expect(attemptedPost).toEqual(post);

  });
});
```

Comment: Unless i'm missing something, you haven't assigned a value to `attemptedPost` when you call `flush(attemptedPost)`.

Comment: @TheHeadRush, I did it  when I subscribe. The good response was gived by Doflamingo19.

Comment: The error you get results from the call of flush with the value >undefined<. The automatic conversion of undefined to json is not defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error is that  `subscribe` method is `async` so you try this:

```
service.getPosts().subscribe( (postRetrieved) => {

      attemptedPost=postRetrieved;

   const req =  httpTestingController.expectOne('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');
   req.flush(attemptedPost);
   // expect(attemptedPost).toEqual(post);

});
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. Can you explain to me the flush() method please?

Comment: the problem is when the method is 'async' like this case (observable,etc) when you do the call you don't know when the call is execute and when is returned value. So you need to put all codes that refer the call return value in the method. With you code the parameter "attemptedPost" is null.

Comment: attemptedPost was not null. Look at inside the subscribe method ().

Answer (score 2):

`flush()` method is what your mock request will return. Think of it as the value coming from the endpoint. In your case if you flush `attemptedPost` is what the endpoint would return, so you need to make sure that attemptedPost's model and the real model coming from the endpoint are the same, so your code actually works.

In your code, you are flushing `attemptedPost` but you never assigned a value to it, you can either assign a value to it or flush `post`.

Also, as the observable is asynchronous you need to move the expectation inside the subscription.

Answer (score 0):

I can't get this code to work in an online runtime environment, but try to let it run, I hope it can give you some insides about the execution order, which imo would help you to understand your code.

```
it("flush should work when it is called outside of the next-function that is given to subscribe", () => {

    let cc: number = -1;

    service.getPosts().subscribe((postRetrieved: ResponseTypeOfGetPosts): void => { // ResponseTypeOfGetPosts as in getPosts(): Observable<ResponseTypeOfGetPosts>

        expect(cc).toEqual(1); // ! not "-1"! - this code is executed by the call of flush(..)

        console.log("I was here -- 2nd --------------------------------------------------------------");

        cc = 2;

        expect(postRetrieved).toEqual(X_Y_Z);
      
    });
    
    const req = httpTestingController.expectOne('your-url-string');

    expect(cc).toEqual(-1);

    console.log("I was here -- 1st --------------------------------------------------------------");

    cc = 1;

    req.flush(X_Y_Z);   // insert a value of the type THIS_TYPE, that you used in your service in httpClient.get<THIS_TYPE>(...)
                        // but fill it, else the value is >undefined< what leads to your error

    expect(cc).toEqual(2);

    console.log("I was here -- 3rd --------------------------------------------------------------");

    cc = 3;
});
```

The second test shows you that in the case of the accepted answer the code inside the anonymous function is never executed.

```
it("should NOT execute code that is never triggered when flush is called from inside of the next-function that is given to subscribe", () => {

    console.log("I was here ... --------------------------------------------------------------");

    service.getPosts().subscribe((postRetrieved: ResponseTypeOfGetPosts): void => { // ResponseTypeOfGetPosts as in getPosts(): Observable<ResponseTypeOfGetPosts>

        console.log(" ... but never here at all --------------------------------------------------------------");

        const req = httpTestingController.expectOne('your-url-string');

        req.flush(X_Y_Z);   // insert a value of the type THIS_TYPE, that you used in your service in httpClient.get<THIS_TYPE>(...)
                            // but fill it, else the value is >undefined< what leads to your error
    });    
});
```

I hope this could help a little bit.